# Will a ZeroMQ inproc PubSub send() call in a realtime thread cause serious blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, zeromq, nonblocking

In general, a ring-buffer is needed for a realtime Producer thread to have decent performance.

But in my case, I have some latency constraints, so I'd love to get rid of the ring-buffer from Producer and push individual data buffers out as they come along. I'd then ring-buffer on the Consumers (slower) side only. And I'd love to avoid thread locking via critical sections.

Since ZMQ requires no thread-locking, I wonder if a `inproc` PubSub pattern can be used for this. Knowing network I/O is not welcomed in a realtime thread, I'm still curious about whether or not the `inproc` protocol could make any difference, i.e., better performance.

So the question is: Can I achieve low-latency lock-free/blocking-free data delivery in a realtime thread using ZMQ PubSub with `inproc` protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q** : *Can I achieve low-latency lock-free/blocking-free data delivery in a realtime thread using ZMQ PubSub with `inproc` protocol?*

Yes.

---

Just enough to instantiate a thread-less **`Context(0)`**-instance :

> No I/O threads are involved in passing messages using the inproc transport. Therefore, if you are using a ØMQ context for in-process messaging only you can initialise the context with zero I/O threads

---

Affinity (wisely planned bonding) tricks may shave-off further a few hundreds `[ns]` due to possible avoiding all R/T processing from bearing extensive add-on latency-costs from core-to-core NUMA-non-local memory accesses.

Comment: @kakyo Glad you have found it interesting and inspiring - StackOverflow encourages Community Members to click [+1] for such interesting or inspiring items in either Questions or Answers and to click [ACCEPT] for the best Answer provided for your Question so far, so do not hesitate to do it - StackOverflow works this way ( as you know it :o)

Comment: Oh yes. I will accept it immediately after I have verified it. Probably tomorrow.